# $\lim_{y \to \infty}\int_{R}f(x-t)\frac{t}{t^2 +y^2}dt=0?$ for $f\in L^{p}$, $p \in [1,\infty)$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, limits, lebesgue-integral

For $f\in L^{p}$, $p \in [1,\infty)$
we want to prove:
$$\lim_{y \to \infty}\int_{R}f(x-t)\frac{t}{t^2 +y^2}dt=0$$

I'm not sure whether we can exchange the limit and the integral, cuz I cannot find the integral function $g(t)$ such that $|f(x-t)\frac{t}{t^2 +y^2}| \leq |g(t)|$.

How could I argue this? Appreciate with any hints!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $p>1$, use Hölder's inequality. Then write 
$$\int_{\Bbb R}\left|\frac{t}{t^2+y^2}\right|^qdt\leqslant \int_{\{|t|\geqslant R\}}\frac 1{|t|^q}dt+(2R)^{Q+1}y^{-2q}.$$

If $p=1$, use dominated convergence theorem, where $|f(x-t)|\frac{|t|}{t^2+1}$ is a dominating function ($y>1$).

Comment: Thank you for your reply. If $p>1$, we need to calculate $\lim_{y \to \infty}\int_{R}|\frac{t}{t^2 +y^2}|^{q}dt=0$ ($1/p +1/q=1$), here $t$ is not bounded, I can't show this integral is 0. Meanwhile, if $p=1$,you mean use dominated convergence theorem, but I can't find the dominated function which satisfied its integral is 0.

Comment: @user39843 See edit.

Comment: First, take the $\limsup_{y\to +\infty}$ in the inequality I wrote, then conclude using the fact that $q>1$ and $R$ is arbitrary.

Comment: Thanks for your kindly answer. For $p=1$, I get your point. For $p>1$,  $$\int_{\{|t|\geqslant R\}}\frac 1{|t|^q}dt+(2R)^{Q+1}y^{-2q}=C\frac{1}{R^{q-1}}+(2R)^{Q+1}y^{-2q}$$. Here, we must let the right hand side be 0, right? So $R$ should be tend to $\infty$, then how could we show $\lim_{y \to \infty}(2R)^{Q+1}y^{-2q}=0$? It is $\frac{\infty}{\infty}$ case. Isn't it?